# Reading from depth textures always returns 1

Tags: opengl

I create a packed depth/stencil texture and attach it to a framebuffer like this:

```
glGenTextures(1,&_depthStencilTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,_depthStencilTexture);
//set filtering to gl_nearest, not shown cause not important
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,width,height,0,GL_DEPTH_STENCIL,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8,nullptr);

//... create framebuffer and attach some color attachments
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,_depthStencilTexture,0);
```

The creation of the framebuffer causes no OpenGL status errors.

In terms of usage for depth and stencil testing, the texture/attachment seems to work correctly. If I disable depth testing, I get the usual artifacts of objects in the back being drawn over objects in the front if they are drawn in the wrong order. If I disable stencil testing, the effects I'm using related to that don't work anymore (I'm masking out areas that shouldn't be lit by the lighting pass). Also, if I simply don't attach the depth/stencil buffer to the framebuffer, the related tests stop working (as expected).

However, reading from that texture in a shader always returns 1 if I read the depth part, and 0 if I read from the stencil part.

I confirmed this via glReadBuffer(GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT) and glReadPixels. All integers read show up as 0xffffff00, directly after clearing them via glClear and a black clearcolor and also after the screen is drawn full of stuff.

Drawing to and reading from the rest of the attached textures (four color buffers for now) works fine.

I have to note that I'm not actually manually drawing anything to the depth-stencil attachment in the fragment shader when rendering - I'm assuming OpenGL automatically draws depth and stencil values to the correct buffer.

What could be the cause of these incorrect values showing up when reading from the texture?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with preview of depth textures, but not from code level, but from CodeXL from AMD. I'm not 100% sure but maybe they try to draw textures in the same way as you.

My solution to see the content of depth attachment is using this simple shader:

```
// vertex
#version 330
in vec4 vertex;

void main(){
    gl_Position=vertex;
}

// fragment
#version 330
out vec4 frag;
uniform vec2 screen; // screen size

uniform texture2D depth;
void main(){
    frag=texture2D(depth,gl_FragCoord/screen);
}
```

to 'depth' pass your _depthStencilTexture and use this shader when rendering fullscreen quad. You can also add linearization to see better what the content of depth attachmnet is.